# arrow prompt repeating in MySQL

Tags: mysql

whenever i type a script with wrong syntax, MySQL command line will just give me the arrow prompt, no matter what i type in.
for example, if i type in a wrong syntax, it will say error, then give me the -> prompt.
I don't know how to get out of it.
whatever i type, it will just give me the -> prompt.
i can type \c, and it will clear, and give me MySQL prompt, but any command i type will again result in the -> prompt.
I can only do a quit and restart the command line.
How do i get out of this repeating MySQL prompt?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `Ctrl-C`?

Comment: @user Type `quit`

Comment: ctrl-c will get me back to mysql>, but if i type in any command, it will give me -> again.

Comment: if i am still in the -> loop, type quit will give me another ->, even with ;

Comment: I think i figure it out.
I use typing a create procedure with delimiter. I ended it with DELIMITER;
There should be a space before the ;
so, i type DELIMITER ;
then it give me back the mysql prompt.
Anyone know why is that?  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you see `->` prompt in MySQL in terminal you should cancel the command - use ctrl +C and then press the Enter key. Then try again your command but don't forget that you have to use a semicolon ; after each command. Do not leave the last line without it too.

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
```

or

```
mysql> USE my_database;
SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

Comment: `mysql> SHOW DATABASES;` -> Still get an arrow prompt

Answer (score 1):

If you're typing the commands correctly then you must have been forgetting to add the semicolon at the end of the commands. Add the semicolon and you'll be fine. I just went through the same mess.